# What is the best way to retrieve all pages of a REST API route with Python aiohttp when the number of pages is unknown?

Tags: python, pagination, asyncio

I've encountered a paginated [API route](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) where there is no way to know the number of available pages.  The only way to retrieve every pages is to check on each page if a next page exists.  To do so, the HTTP response of any query contains a header called `x-next-page`, if it holds an integer bigger than the current page number, that means there is a next page.

I've came with the following design.  It is possible to test it with a Gitlab account and a [personnel access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#create-a-personal-access-token).

The API is quite slow and I love the idea of being able to trigger the download of the next page before having processed the current page data.  But I don't like having a loop waiting for every tasks to be completed.  Does anyone could think of a better design than this one ?

````py
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                          
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                         
                                                                                
import aiohttp                                                                  
import asyncio                                                                  
                                                                                
TOKEN = ""  # PUT YOUR PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN HERE.
URL = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token={}&page={}"             
                                                                                
async def get_next_projects(session, index):                                    
    print("process page {}".format(index))                                      
    url = URL.format(TOKEN, index)                                              
                                                                                
    next_task = None                                                            
    async with session.get(url) as response:                                    
        # starting next page request if any                                     
        next_index = int(response.headers["x-next-page"])                       
        if index < next_index:                                                  
            next_task = asyncio.create_task(get_next_projects(session, next_index)) 
                                                                                   
        # processing results                                                       
        data = await response.json()                                            
                                                                                
        # .... do some process on data ....                                     
                                                                                
    return next_task                                                            
                                                                                
async def get_list():                                                           
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:                              
        next_task = await get_next_projects(session, 1)                         
                                                                                
        while next_task is not None:                                            
            await next_task                                                     
            next_task = next_task.result()                                      
                                                                                
                                                                                
asyncio.run(get_list()) 
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Don't format your token and page parameters into your URL. `aiohttp` supports passing a [params dict to `get`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html).

I assume that you've already carefully read [the documentation describing API pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/):

> - `x-next-page`:  The index of the next page.
> - `x-page`:   The index of the current page (starting at 1).
> - `x-per-page`:   The number of items per page.
> - `X-prev-page`:  The index of the previous page.
> - `x-total`:  The total number of items.
> - `x-total-pages`:    The total number of pages.

and that the headers other than the first one are missing.

Algorithmically, this leaves you with either

1. kick off a batch of simultaneous requests with contiguous page numbers starting at the last known valid page number;
2. when any returns, if it's a valid page number, update your best guess for the page count and kick off a new request;
3. iterate until `x-next-page` is missing.

Or perform a binary search with an estimated bound:

1. kick off a batch of simultaneous requests with exponential spacing. For example, with a first estimate for page count at 20, a worker count of 4 and an exponentiation base of *e*, your initial page indices would be rounded to 1, 3, 7 and 20.
2. If they are all valid pages, multiply by some growth factor and try again.
3. If one or more requests indicates an invalid page, perform a parallel binary search to find the end of the page sequence.